# What’s the Eastern Orthodox belief on the Lake of Fire?

Tags: eastern-orthodox

How does Eastern Orthodox view the lake of fire and “eternal judgment“ (hebrew 6:2)?

Comment: This discussion quotes many church fathers and exposes the diversity of opinion on the matter among Orthodox believers: http://www.orthodoxchristianity.net/forum/index.php?topic=26914.0